# java when I invoked Thread.sleep(), the data's visibility

Tags: java, multithreading

Look at this code:

```
public class VolatileTest {

    private static boolean ready = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ready = true;
                System.out.println("t2 thread should stop!");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
               while(!ready){
                   System.out.println("invoking..");
               }
                System.out.println("I was finished");
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

I think the result of this code maybe:

```
t2 thread should stop!
invoking..
I was finished
```

because of in the multithreading, when the t1 modify 'ready' variable to true,then I made t1 sleep. At the moment, I think, to t2 the 'ready' variable is false!!! because t1 thread is not stop, the variable in t1 is invisible in t2.
But in fact.. I test many times. the result is always this:

[image]

Am my idea is wrong?

Comment: If  your idea clearly does not match reality, it is wrong. What is your real question?

Comment: It's a classic concurrence issue. Just notice that the `ready = true` is being called "usually really fast", even before the second thread is started

Comment: There is no guarantee what value thread t2 will see for `ready`, because of improper synchronization in your code. It could be `true`, it could be `false`. In your case, t2 saw `true`. That is consistent with "there is no guarantee what value t2 will see"

Comment: If you really want a better synchronization and order in execution of Threads consider using [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

Comment: I just want to know in multithreading, if I not use the 'volatile' keyword,the data in A thread is invisible or visible in B thread?

Comment: It's not that the data is not visible, it's that changes might not reflect between threads.

Comment: Maybe `volatile` is actually not needed _here_ because of the JIT compilation still does not take over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, despite calling your class `VolatileTest`, you are not actually using `volatile` anywhere in your code.

Since the `ready` variable is not declared as `volatile` AND you are accessing it without any explicit synchronization, the behavior is *not specified*.  Specifically, the JLS does not say whether the assignment made in thread 1 to the `ready` variable will be visible within thread 2.

Indeed, there is not even guaranteed that the `run()` method for thread 1 will be called before the `run()` method for thread 2.

Now it seems that your code (as written!) is behaving in a way that is *consistent with* the write of `true` always being visible immediately.  However, there is no *guarantee* that that "always" is actually always, or that this will be the case on every Java platform.

I would not be surprised if the syscall associated with `sleep` is triggering memory cache flushing before the second thread is scheduled.  That would be sufficient to cause consistent behavior.  Moreover, there is likely to be serendipitous synchronization<sup>1</sup> due to the `println` calls.  However, these are not effects you should ever rely on.

---

<sup>1 - Somewhere in the output stream stack for `System.out`, the `println` call is likely to synchronize on the stream's shared data structures.  Depending on the ordering of the events, this can have the effect of inserting a *happens before* relationship between the write and read events.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, there are no guarantees. ("There is no guarantee what value thread t2 will see for ready, because of improper synchronization in your code. It could be true, it could be false. In your case, t2 saw true. That is consistent with "there is no guarantee what value t2 will see")

You can easily get your test to fail by running it multiple times.
When I run below code that does your test 100 times, I always get 14-22 "notReadies", so 14-22% of the cases you will not see the change to `ready` in Thread t2.

```
public class NonVolatileTest {

    private static boolean ready = false;

    private static volatile int notReadies = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            ready = false;

            // Copy original Thread 1 code from the OP here

            Thread t2 = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!ready) {
                        notReadies++;
                    }
                    while (!ready) {
                        System.out.println("invoking..");
                    }
                    System.out.println("I was finished");
                }
            };

            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            // To reduce total test run time, reduce the sleep in t1 to a 
            // more suitable value like "100" instead of "5000".
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        }
        System.out.println("Notreadies: " + notReadies);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1)  Do you need to `join()` the two threads at the end of each iteration?  2) The use of a `volatile` counter *could* change the behavior.

Comment: @StephenC You're right. Doing that (and reducing the sleep in t1 to 100 ms - otherwise it takes more than 8 minutes to run) reduces the number of "notReadies" to 2.

Comment: @StephenC The volatile counter only gets accessed *when* there is a race condition. The OP claims there's never a race condition, and in that case it doesn't get accessed.